# Why can't we use infinitives after prepositions, and only gerunds?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

I've had the question of: Why can't we use infinitives after prepositions if the infinitives and gerunds can both act as verbal nouns?

Comment: How might you want to use an infinitive after a preposition, if doing so was syntactically valid? What might be the *semantic* implications?

Comment: I assume you're thinking that in *I like **swimming / to swim***, the highlighted elements are both "verbs functioning as nouns". But whereas I can say *I thought **about** swimming*, I can't say *I thought about **to swim***. That's just the way English works, I guess.

Comment: ...but I can say *I sat **down to eat***, which looks like a preposition followed by an infinitive to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "down" is an adverb there, not a preposition, and "to eat" is a short version of "in order to eat", not the mere infinitive "to eat". It also fails the cleft sentence test: *"***It's down to eat** that I sat*"

Comment: In archaic usage, I believe you *could* use the infinitive after one specific preposition: **for**. "I came to the table **for to eat** dinner."

Comment: I think the answer is just "because that's the way it's done in English". Similarly, I could imagine constructions that might use the bare infinitive or *that* or *of*, but we don't do it that way.